# Cypress origin command using dynamic data in a secondary origin

Tags: cypress, cypress-origin

I am trying to follow the following [code from the Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Using-dynamic-data-in-a-secondary-origin).

```
cy.origin(
  'supersecurelogons.com',
  // Send the args here...
  { args: sentArgs },
  // ...and receive them at the other end here!
  ({ username, password }) => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('input#username').type(username)
    cy.get('input#password').type(password)
    cy.contains('button', 'Login').click()
  }
)
```

The code that I am using is below. My problem is that both `pathname` & `search` are undefined, this means that the visit command is failing.

I was wondering what it is that I am doing wrong here, any help gratefully received.

```
const workaroundUrl = new URL('https://www.validurl.com/pathname?search=true');
const url = { pathname: workaroundUrl.pathname, search: workaroundUrl.search }
cy.origin(workaroundUrl.origin, { args: { url } }, ({ pathname, search }) => {
  cy.visit(pathname + search);
});
```

I am using v10.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to match up the brackets (send and receive) like this

```js
const workaroundUrl = new URL('https://www.validurl.com/pathname?search=true');
const url = { pathname: workaroundUrl.pathname, search: workaroundUrl.search }

cy.origin(workaroundUrl.origin, { args: {url} }, ({url}) => {

  const { pathname, search } = url;  // destructure the url arg

  cy.visit(pathname + search);
});
```

That would make the example you mentioned incorrect.

I've used this pattern successfully [origin - Usage](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Usage)

```js
cy.origin('https://www.acme.com', { args: { hits } }, ({ hits }) => {
```

Comment: Thank you Fody, that's working just fine, I appreciate ti.